# Website Forms (POST) On Multiple Instances (Servers) Website (Python Django / PHP)

Tags: django, forms, instances

Suppose I have a PHP / Python (Django) website.
The website is running on multiple instances servers.
Meaning the URL for the website is www.test.com, and from a load balancer, it can get the client to www.server1.com or www.server2.com and so on.

When there is a form on the website, and the processing of this form is located on the same page:
Can the following situation exist ? :
- User go to www.test.com - behind the scenes, through the load balancer, he gets to www.server**1**.com. He fills a form.
- The form action (URL) is for www.test.com - so behind the scenes, through the load balancer, he gets to www.server**2**.com.
So here, will the needed form data, and more important for my question maybe - the 'request' data, (like request.SOMETHING at Python Django) will be missing ? Because maybe it was saved before on the session, at www.server**1**.com, and now it is missing at www.server**2**.com ?

Answer (score 0):

The request will always have all data, as that gets forwarded to the edge server. `request.POST` and `request.GET` will have all the data from the request. The problem however, is that the session data might not be available at that edge server. Example, you started your session on server1, then request another page from server2. server2 might assign a new session and forbid you to access certain contents.

To overcome this session problem, you can do one of two things:

1. Share sessions between servers (central session storage)
2. Always forward the user to the same edge server. Some loadbalancers store the forwared-to edge server in a cookie. On subsequent requests, the user gets forwarded to the same edge node every time. That same edge node will keep the session of that user, so no problems.

Comment: If you want to have a fail-over, however, option 2 is not enough by itself (without option 1). Imagine that you save the session on the first server, and on the next request the server is unavailable. You have lost the state for the client.

Comment: @UkuLoskit I do not see how the website would work without the failing load-balancer in the first place. However, providing a fail-safe would be a good idea.

Comment: sorry I meant server, not load-balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a valid concern. Due to the nature of the Web (HTTP), the other request might end up on the other server. This issue is called persistence or stickiness.

The solution here would be to save all this information on the client side (using cookies) and not rely on server-side sessions. So it would be up to you to implement it like this using Python/Django. Using the client-side approach gives the best performance, and should be the easiest to implement.

Keep in mind that this solution bears quite a significant security risk for man-in-the-middle attacks, unless you encrypt the connection with SSL/TSL (using HTTPS), as all of the client data is stored in the cookies which could be intercepted.